# How to return sub classes in c# extensions?

Tags: c#, methods, subclass, extension-methods

I have this extension method.

```
    public static List<Framework.Model> FetchAll(this Framework.Model model)
    {
        List<Framework.Model> models = new List<Framework.Model>();

        StringBuilder Fields = new StringBuilder();

        var properties = GetProperties(model);

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (!p.Name.Equals("Table"))

                Fields.Append(p.Name + ",");
        }

        Fields.Length--;


        System.Data.DataTable data = (System.Data.DataTable)engine.RunDataTable("select " + Fields.ToString() + " from " + model.Table + ";").Data;


        foreach (System.Data.DataRow rw in data.Rows)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in data.Columns)
            {
                foreach (var p in properties)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName.Equals(p.Name))
                    {
                        if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                        {
                            p.SetValue(model, DateTime.Parse(rw[col.ColumnName].ToString()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            p.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(rw[col.ColumnName], p.PropertyType));

                        }
                    }

                }

            }


            models.Add(model);

        }

        return models;


    }
```

and I have this base class.

```
public interface Model
{
    string Table { get; set; }
}
```

and I also have this sub class.

```
 public class Department : Framework.Model
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Table = "departments";
    }

    public int Dbid { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }

    public string Table
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

i now tried to use the extension method above.

```
List<Model.Department> depts = new List<Model.Department>();
depts = new Model.Department().FetchAll();
```

but its a compiler error since it cannot cast the base class to sub class.
my question only is how to return a sub class because all i want is when i call the extension method it will return all the data on the database on that certain table which is my sub class so i want to fetch a list of sub classes.

BTW the extension method is I want that to be flexible that can accept different sub classes that's why i build it that way.

Comment: It seems odd to have to create an instance of your `Model.Department` object to be able to fetch all of the items. Why are you doing it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. You just need to make it generic.

```
public static List<T> FetchAll<T>(this T model) where T: Framework.Model
{
    List<T> models = new List<T>();
    ...
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow rw in data.Rows)
    {
        <... modifying model's properties ...>
        models.Add(model);
    }
    ...
    return models;
}
```

After that you will not even need to specify generic type - the compiler will infer it from your code:

```
var depts = new Model.Department().FetchAll();
// depts is List<Model.Department> if you've built class hierarchy correctly
```

However, there's one more problem with your code. Let's take a look at the loop above. You're trying to add the same object to the list over and over again. Since you're modifying properties of your object you'll end up with the list of N references to the same object with the properties from the last row of the table you fetched from DB. I don't believe that this is what you actually needed, but I didn't actually get what you do need, so can't really advise anything unless you clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a generic Extension method, with a [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of `Framework.Model`:

```
 public static List<T> FetchAll(this T model) where T:Framework.Model
 {
     List<T> models = new List<T>();
     //...    
     return models;
 }
```

<sub>*untested code</sub>